# Change graphic card Mac pro Boot screen disappear

Tags: mac

I've just changed the Graphics card on my Mac Pro 3,1. I've installed a Nvidia Quadro FX 4800. Everything is fine, the only thing is the when I boot the Mac the classic grey screen with the Apple logo and a progress bar has disappeared. When pressing the button the screen is black and then it goes directly to the password screen. How can I do to make the silver screen return?